# Expect/tcl: How to check if each element of a list printed on screen is within a user defined list?

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

Hi potential lifesavers,

I am dealing with a bash program which will print out lines into the command line such as:

```
Which LYSINE type do you want for residue 4
0. Not protonated (charge 0) (LYS)
1. Protonated (charge +1) (LYSH)

Type a number:0
Which LYSINE type do you want for residue 16
0. Not protonated (charge 0) (LYS)
1. Protonated (charge +1) (LYSH)

Type a number:0
Which LYSINE type do you want for residue 22
0. Not protonated (charge 0) (LYS)
1. Protonated (charge +1) (LYSH)

Type a number:0
Which LYSINE type do you want for residue 62
0. Not protonated (charge 0) (LYS)
1. Protonated (charge +1) (LYSH)

Type a number:0
```

At each stage where it says `Type a number:`, the program will await user input, which will be the number 0 or 1, as described above (I have typed 0's above as default).

As these lists can be a few hundred long, I am trying to write an expect script to automate this process. Previously I wrote such a script which does the job, but is very manual and confusing for others to use:

```
#! /usr/bin/expect -f 
set timeout 2

# wanted lysine charges
set LYS_1 "4"
set LYS_2 "16"

set LYS "Which LYSINE type do you want for residue "

expect
  set timeout -1  
  spawn bash test.sh 
  expect {  
    #Lysine charge and default settings; 0 = non-protonated (0), 1 = protonated (+1)
    ${LYS}${LYS_1} {
      send "1\r"
      exp_continue
    }

    ${LYS}${LYS_2} {
      send "1\r"
      exp_continue
    }

    ${LYS} {
      send "0\r"
      exp_continue
    }
```

Where the script encountered `Which LYSINE type do you want for residue` followed by `4` or `16`, it would enter 1, or if the number was not recognised, enter 0 by default. There are multiple problems with this format: if I wanted to extend the number of `LYS_X` variables, I would need to set these at the top, and also add additional sets of

```
${LYS}${LYS_1} {
    send "1\r"
    exp_continue
}
```

into the bottom section. The second issue is that if expect is asked to set residue 4 to 1, it will also accidentally set all other numbers beginning with 4, to 1, e.g. 42, 400, 40006, etc.

I've tried tidying this with a foreach loop:

```
#! /usr/bin/expect

set timeout 1

set LYS "Which LYSINE type do you want for residue "

expect
    set timeout -1
    spawn bash test.sh

    foreach q [list "4" "16"] {
        set LYS_q $q

        expect {
            ${LYS}${LYS_q} {
                send "1\r"
                exp_continue
            }

            ${LYS} {
                send "0\r"
                exp_continue
            }
        }
    }
```

Where any residue numbers which need to be set to "1", can be included in `[list "4" "16"]`, however this doesn't seem to work and only the first element in the list is set, with everything else set to 0. The `test.sh` script then terminates, and `LYS_q` then set to the second element. Surely I can't have the `spawn bash test.sh` command within the foreach loop either?

If anyone could give me some guidance on how I could solve this issue, I would be very grateful. I'm new to stackoverflow, so if I have missed any useful information, please don't hesitate to ask!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use regex matching:

```
set question {Which LYSINE type do you want for residue (\d+)}
set lysines {4 16}

spawn bash test.sh

expect  {
    -re $question {
        if {$expect_out(1,string) in $lysines} {
            send "1\r"
        } else {
            send "0\r"
        }
        exp_continue
    }
}
```

The `in` operator is relatively new. If your expect does not have it, use

```
if {[lsearch -exact $lysines $expect_out(1,string)] != -1}
```

If your expect **does** have `in`, you can shorten the above to this, because the returned value will be the boolean 1 or 0 which you can send as a string.

```
expect  {
    -re $question {
        set response [expr {$expect_out(1,string) in $lysines}]
        send "$response\r"
        exp_continue
    }
}
```